# Google Adward Conversion Tracking in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, google-analytics, conversion

We have recently set up a Magento community site running 1.9.0.1 having moved from go.

We are trying to set up the google AdWords conversion tracking, there is a piece of code that they want placing on the success page.

Where is this located in 1.9.0.1?

Answer (score 2):

The File is **success.phtml**

and is located at (Can vary if you are using any other theme than default)

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/success.phtml
```

> Modifying the success-page boils down to copying the PHTML-template
>   template/checkout/success.phtml from the Magento core theme folder
>   app/design/frontend/base/default to your own theming folder
>   app/design/frontend/default/YOURTHEME.

To be sure turn on `template hints` and view template

To enable template path hints follow the following steps:

1. Go to Magento admin panel->systems->configuration.
2. Choose your store view on top left corner in Current Configuration Scope ex: English.
3. Go to Advanced tab. Under that click on Developer->Debug. ...
4. hit the place order button to land on order success page.

you can take a hint form below code

You can copy and paste the following piece of code in your **success.phtml**

```
<?php
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$total = (float)number_format($order()->getSubtotal(),2);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 'CONVERSION_ID';
var google_conversion_language = "LANG_CODE";
var google_conversion_format = "FORMAT";
var google_conversion_color = "COLOR";
var google_conversion_label = "LABEL";
if (<?php echo $total?>) {
    var google_conversion_value = <?php echo $total?>;
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt=""
src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/CONVERSION_ID/?value=<?php echo $total?>&amp;label=LABEL&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

Make sure you change the following variables in the above code -:

- `CONVERSION_ID` (e.g. `999999999`)
- `LANG_CODE` (e.g. `en`)
- `FORMAT` (e.g. `1`)
- `COLOR` (e.g. `#ffffff`)
- `LABEL` (e.g. `-9C8CICMuggQ4O_B1wM`)

Hope it helps!

Comment: So where I put the conversion code because google says that paste before body close but there is no Body in Magento so where I suppose to paste the code

Comment: added more code , you can paste at very end of the file.Accept answer if it helped you

Comment: I already try but it not showing page source code

Comment: are you sure that you are pasting on right template  file ?

Comment: yes app/design/frontend/mypackage/mytemplate/template/checkout/success.phtml  This is my path

Comment: add the code of the file with question ... meanwhile try altering other content of that page and check are they reflecting on that page . if not , try clearing cache and browser cache

Comment: I did that still not working